# Sort values in pandas dataframe by key similarly to python's sorted()

Tags: python, pandas

I need to sort a dataframe by a custom aggregation function, for example, the sum of their values, similarly to the `sorted` function with the `key` argument:

```
sorted([(1, 10), (1, 2), (2, 3)], key=sum)
```

which gives:

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 10)]
```

I know that in pandas I could create a new aggregate column and sort by column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 10), (1, 2), (2, 3)])
df[2] = df.sum(axis=1)
df.sort_values(2).drop(2, axis=1)
```

But as you can see it is way less elegant than the python solution with `sorted()`.
Since `sort_values()` does not take a key argument, what would be a way to sort values in a dataframe by key without creating new columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html) with [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html) for general solution working with any index values:

```
print (df.iloc[df.sum(axis=1).argsort()])
   0   1
1  1   2
2  2   3
0  1  10
```

Comment: How would this be possible for operations where pandas does a sort internally, say during a groupby or pivot?

Answer (score 4):

No need to add a dummy column, just use the result of `df.sum(1)` to index your dataframe:

```
df.loc[df.sum(1).argsort()]
# Use @jezraels answer if the index is not range(len(df.index))

   0   1
1  1   2
2  2   3
0  1  10
```

Comment: Nice and simple, thanks! Accepted @jezrael's answer as more general